# absolute div positioning algorithm using

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm

What is the best way to position multiple divs with differing sizes on the screen while taking advantage of as much space as possible.  It will have to get the width and height of each div and decide the most optimal arrangement like a puzzle.

Comment: If one div, make it 0,0 and the width and height of the screen. If two, make each half the width of the screen. Otherwise... I don't know what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm looking for a practical solution to the Knapsack problem using javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to use a plug-in, take a look at [jQuery Masonry](http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/). If you want to try to code this yourself, the [Masonry source code](https://github.com/desandro/masonry/raw/master/jquery.masonry.js) may give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Set up an array with the sizes of the divs (getAttribute(); 'width' and 'height',

get the size of the browser window,

iterate through the div array, take the divs of the same height and add widths up,

if you get to the width of the browser window, add them, else take the closest number and add them.

At the point you run out of divs of the same height, find same width divs and add them vertically instead if you can fit it in the remainder of the window. (Don't forget to shrink the browser window variable)

This will fill the window from the top left and work towards the bottom right.

Finally when you're left with only 'odd' divs, simply add the biggest in width and height, and work your way down.